# Could a tailed beast become a Jinchuriki

Tags: naruto

I know that together all the tailed beast create the ten tails but could a tailed beast be sealed inside another tailed beast. Excluding the ten tails of course.

Comment: To make the Ten Tails you atleast need the Tailed Beasts or their chakra. So that means if you take the chakra of the Tailed Beast it will be pretty weak, so it won't be able to become a vessel for the other Tailed Beast. But also Tailed Beast have a massive amount of chakra. Also if humans were trying to make a Tailed Beast a "jinchuriki", they would have to control it first. Which is hard to do. Than put the other Tailed Beast in there. Which they would have to control too.

Answer (score 3):

No.  It's also never been explored in any official capacity, either.

Jinchuriki means ["power of human sacrifice"](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jinch%C5%ABriki).  This implies that only a human can take on the immense energies of a tailed beast.